# Can Enterprise Architect reverse engineer state machine diagram from source code?

Tags: state-machine, enterprise-architect

I'm new to Enterprise Architect. I would like to generate state machine diagrams from C source code, but I can't find any tutorial on this. Does EA have such functionality? If not, what would be the best work around?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

And getting such a thing to work looks like a nice punishment for Sisyphus. Even more for that Oh So OO C ;-)

The "work around" is called brain...